# Why bootstrap collapse is automatically collapsing(shrinking) the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using the AngularJs with HTML to have dynamic content.

I am also making use of bootstrap for collapse feature.

I have created question answer page which is similar to Stackoverflow.

When page loads, it shows up the all questions and when I click on any particular question then it expands that question and with answers but answers are again collpased and there is one anchor tag to expand all answers.

My problem is that when I am clicking on  answer's anchor tag the answers are showing up for few seconds and again it is collapsing automatically.

Below is my code:

```
<div style="" class="row ans-txt left-margin-img">
    {{ answer.a_list.as.length }} ANSWERS
    <a data-target=".demo" data-parent="" data-toggle="collapse">
        <img src="assets/svg/downarrow_active.svg" class="img-responsive" style="height: 24px; width: 24px; display: inline; float: right; right: 18px; position: absolute;"></img>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="row " style="padding-top:14px;height:auto;" ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in answer.a_list.as">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 content-padding2 collapse demo">
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="searchStyle bgStyle btn-Style vote-btn-border" ng-click="vote(value.raw, 1)">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
    <img src="assets/svg/uparrow.svg" class="img-responsive" style="height:24px;width:24px;"></img>
     </button>
        </div>
        <div><button type="text" class="searchStyle bgStyle  btn-txt" disabled>{{ value.raw.netvotes }}</button></div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="searchStyle bgStyle btn-Style vote-btn-border" ng-click="vote(value.raw, 0)">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    <img src="assets/svg/downarrow_active.svg" class="img-responsive" style="height:24px;width:24px;"></img>
    </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-10 col-md-11 padding-rightPane collapse demo">
        <p class="ex2">{{ value.raw.content }}</p>
        <p class="bottom-margin14">
            <div class="askedBy-txt">
                Answered by {{ value.raw.handle ? value.raw.handle : value.raw.email }} on {{ value.raw.created * 1000 | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'}}
            </div>
            <img src="assets/svg/tick_icon.svg" style="height:20px;width:20px;" class="img-responsive pull-right" title="Best answer"
                ng-if="value.select_text === 'Best answer'"></img>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when including bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js twice.

Comment: @B3rn475: Ohh..But in my case, I have added bootstrap.js once!

Comment: are you activating the collapse manually? as in http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript-3

Comment: @B3rn475 No I am not activating it manually. One thing is sure, it is due to dynamic AngularJs Content

Comment: Why not moving to angular directives for bootstrap? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Try to toogle the class `.collapse.in`. It toogles the css state of collapse element.

```
<div class="...collapse..." ng-class="{'in': !isCollapsed}">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not helping.

Comment: It is because you shared only html. Isn't possible investigate what could be happening without a complete scenario.